# Konva real time update a rect position

Tags: javascript, html, animation, canvas, konvajs

I got two draggable rectangles in Konva, taken from this [tutorial](https://konvajs.github.io/docs/drag_and_drop/Drag_and_Drop.html).

My goal is to have the red (NON draggable) rectangle in a position average of the blue draggable rectangle at all times.

I tried changing this from the tutorial code:

```
box1.on('mouseover', function() {
    document.body.style.cursor = 'pointer';
    center.x = (box1.x() + box2.x() ) / 2; // added
    center.y = (box1.y() + box2.y()) / 2; // added
});
```

Where center is the red rectangle that I would like to keep in the middle.

I think that the problem is that `center.x = (box1.x() + box2.x() ) / 2;` creates a new variable instead of changing the position of the rect as I would like.

I also added:

```
stage.on('contentMousemove', function () {
  layer.batchDraw();
});
```

But still, it does not work.

How can I update the `x` and `y` coordinates of the center rect in real time and see it move while I drag one of the others?

Minimal example where the problem can be seen:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/konvajs/konva/2.1.7/konva.min.js"></script>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Interactive center of mass simulation</title>
    <p>Drag the blue rectangles around, they have mass proportional to their area.

The red rectangle, that reresents the center of mass will move in real time<p>
    <style>
        body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            overflow: hidden;
            background-color: #F0F0F0;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container"></div>
<script>
    var width = window.innerWidth;
    var height = window.innerHeight;

    var stage = new Konva.Stage({
        container: 'container',
        width: width,
        height: height
    });

    var layer = new Konva.Layer();


    var box1 = new Konva.Rect({
        x: 100,
        y: 100,
        width: 50,
        height: 50,
        fill: '#00D2FF',
        stroke: 'black',
        strokeWidth: 4,
        draggable: true
    });

    var box2 = new Konva.Rect({
        x: 200,
        y: 100,
        width: 50,
        height: 50,
        fill: '#00D2FF',
        stroke: 'black',
        strokeWidth: 4,
        draggable: true
    });


    var center = new Konva.Rect({
        x: (box1.x() + box2.x() ) / 2,
        y: (box1.y() + box2.y() ) / 2,
        width: 50,
        height: 50,
        fill: '#FF0000',
        stroke: 'black',
        strokeWidth: 4,
        draggable: false
    });


    box1.on('mouseover', function() {
        document.body.style.cursor = 'pointer';
        center.x = (box1.x() + box2.x() ) / 2;
        center.y = (box1.y() + box2.y()) / 2;
    });
    box1.on('mouseout', function() {
        document.body.style.cursor = 'default';
    });

    box2.on('mouseover', function() {
        document.body.style.cursor = 'pointer';
        center.x = (box1.x() + box2.x() ) / 2;
        center.y = (box1.y() + box2.y()) / 2;
    });
    box2.on('mouseout', function() {
        document.body.style.cursor = 'default';
    });

    layer.add(box1);
    layer.add(box2);

    layer.add(center);
    stage.add(layer);
    stage.on('contentMousemove', function () {
      layer.batchDraw();
    });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to move the center object you need to use [center.move](https://konvajs.github.io/api/Konva.Rect.html#move__anchor)

Here is a fully functional example

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/konvajs/konva/2.1.7/konva.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container"></div>
<script>
function KonvaRect(x, y, fill, draggable) {
    return new Konva.Rect({
        x: x, y: y, width: 50, height: 50,
        fill: fill, stroke: 'black',
        strokeWidth: 4, draggable: draggable
    });
}
var box1 = KonvaRect(50, 50, '#00D2FF', true);
var box2 = KonvaRect(200, 50, '#00D2FF', true);
var center = KonvaRect(125, 50, '#FF0000', false);

var layer = new Konva.Layer();
layer.add(box1);
layer.add(box2);
layer.add(center);

var stage = new Konva.Stage({
    container: 'container', width: 600, height: 170
});
stage.add(layer);

function moveCenter() {
    var x = ((box1.x() + box2.x() ) / 2) - center.x();
    var y = ((box1.y() + box2.y() ) / 2) - center.y();
    if (x != 0 || y != 0) {
        center.move({  x: x,  y: y })
        layer.batchDraw();
    }
}

stage.on('contentMousemove', function () {
    moveCenter();
});
box1.on('mouseover', function() {
    document.body.style.cursor = 'pointer';
});
box1.on('mouseout', function() {
    document.body.style.cursor = 'default';
});
box2.on('mouseover', function() {
    document.body.style.cursor = 'pointer';
});
box2.on('mouseout', function() {
    document.body.style.cursor = 'default';
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Very clear code, thanks a lot. I got a few doubts: What is the function of `if (x != 0 || y != 0)`? In case I add more boxes, can I condense `on mouseover` and `on mouseout` in a single loop? Is it possible to make the center rect move while the rect is being dragged? For me it works but the center moves only after I release the bue draggable rect.

Comment: The function of `if (x != 0 || y != 0)` is to prevent calling the batchDraw when is not needed. You can do a lot of thing just test and see, I'm not an expert on this topic... And yes I noticed that Konva is a bit slow rendering the move, maybe you should try with a different framework.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions for frameworks for this small demo?

Comment: Look into a gaming framework: https://github.com/collections/javascript-game-engines